# DeepFace.detectFace() throws ValueError("Confirm that ",img," exists")

Tags: python, deepface

I am trying to identify and count the number of human faces in a every picture of a folder full of pictures, I am using Deepface to get the job done. I have only found one reference to the function `DeepFace.detectFace()` on the web, that supposedly identifies the faces, but I am having some issues implementing the framework properly and I haven't found any other reference of this function other than this one: [Face Alignment for Face Recognition in Python within OpenCV](https://sefiks.com/2020/02/23/face-alignment-for-face-recognition-in-python-within-opencv/)

The input files are "jpg" and "jpeg" files only.

My code is the following:

```
from deepface import DeepFace
import os
import os.path
import numpy as np

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
imgs = []
path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
valid_images = [".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".tga", ".jpeg"]
# image = Image.open(os.path.join(path, file))

for file in os.listdir(path):
    print(file)
    ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    print(ext)
    image_face = DeepFace.detectFace(file)
    print(image_face)
```

And I get the following error:

```
2020-08-17 22:33:34.148103: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-08-17 22:33:34.148135: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/image_cleaning-iUI7F59N/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:120: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
150_save_2020-08-17-21:44:28_9245.png
.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_detection.py", line 18, in <module>
    image_face = DeepFace.detectFace(file)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/image_cleaning-iUI7F59N/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepface/DeepFace.py", line 513, in detectFace
    img = functions.detectFace(img_path)[0] #detectFace returns (1, 224, 224, 3)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/image_cleaning-iUI7F59N/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deepface/commons/functions.py", line 200, in detectFace
    raise ValueError("Confirm that ",img," exists")
ValueError: ('Confirm that ', '150_save_2020-08-17-21:44:28_9245.png', ' exists')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving a file name as the input. You should be giving the image array.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, file))
image_face = DeepFace.detectFace(img)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great! Image_face gives me the image matrix. Do you know how to count how many faces are in every picture?

Comment: You can use `cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml').detectMultiScale(img)` The output of this code will be a numpy array (x, 4). The number x is the number of faces in the current image.

Answer (score 1):

```
from deepface import DeepFace
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2
import os

dire = r"path of the folder"
count = 0
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(dire)):
    path = dire+'/'+img
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        result = DeepFace.analyze(img, actions= ['gender'])
        if result['gender'] == "Man" or result['gender'] == "Woman":
            count += 1
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(count)
```

Initiated a count variable to count the no of images in which the human face is found. The human faces can be either man or woman as per the deepface package.

Answer (score 0):

Passing exact image path to detectFace function works well instead of reading it via opencv.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
img = DeepFace.detectFace("img1.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

deepface is desgined to work with single image. even if an image with multiple faces, it will ignore them and work with the first one.

I recommend you to use [retina-face](https://github.com/serengil/retinaface) to detect faces.

```
#!pip install retina-face
from retinaface import RetinaFace
resp = RetinaFace.detect_faces("img1.jpg")
num_of_faces = len(list(resp.keys()))
```